# Accessing Neo4j db from multiple instance throws error

Tags: neo4j

When I try to invoke the graph db from multiple instance, I'm getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@9446e4' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at 
org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:284)
```

So how could I over come this issue and make it available to process any request from any instance.

Answer (score 2):

Any one database can only be accessed from one process at a time, exclusively. If you would like a cluster of replicated databases please have a look at setting up neo4j in high availability: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha.html

Comment: Even though if i implement clusters (lest say 3 cluster) i can't able to access all clusters from more than 3 instance parallely. So how could i address this problem, if i release search engine with grabh db as datasource ?? how could it accessible from various instance i.e) searches.??

Comment: This is just per VM / Process, if you expose the database via a suitable API to the outside (server, http, binary) then you can use as many remote clients as you want to.